# A scroll view that interacts with a UIPageContol? What is the code for this?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift

In **SWIFT**, I have a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl.

I have the code for a first launch of an app, and I have the scroll view added.

I have `scrollView.pages = true`

How do I add programmatic "objects" to specific pages, and how do I make the page control interact with the pages to show what page it is on>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't exactly add objects to a "page", you add them as subview like normal. When you enable paging on a scroll view, it doesn't break up how the objects in its content area are distributed, all it does is make it so that when you release from dragging the scroll view, it will snap to the nearest "page" (or interval of page number * width) ((roughly)).

Then as far as making your scroll view interact with page control goes, the basic idea is to implement a UIScrollViewDelegate method, like [scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDecelerating%3a), where you can change the page control's [currentPage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uipagecontrol_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPageControl/currentPage) property to reflect the current page of the scroll view based on its content offset. You'll also want to add an action for the page control's UIControlEventValueChanged control event, in which you can convert the new "page" number to a content offset to pass to the scroll view.

Comment: My scroll view is landscape, so does that basically mean I have a 2272 width page that I can put stuff on, and it goes to different pages?

Comment: Also, how do I add a specific number of pages? And, should I have these lines?                                                       `let tutScrollX: CGFloat = tutorialScrollView.frame.size.width
        let tutScrollY: CGFloat = tutorialScrollView.frame.size.width
        
        tutorialScrollView.contentOffset.y = tutScrollX
        tutorialScrollView.contentOffset.x = tutScrollY`